# Swift expected ',' separator error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview

Hi sorry I'm new to xcode and swift and I am having trouble with my UIWebView code

I'm getting an expected ',' separator error in my code

```
@IBOutlet var WebView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://heartburncenterofcalifornia.com/testimonials/")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    UIWebView.loadRequest(_ request: NSURLRequest)
}
```

PLEASE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO FIX IT

the error is on the UIWebView.loadRequest(_ request: NSURLRequest) line

UPDATE: I did that and now it's coming up with a thread 1: signal SIGABRT error

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

on that^ line of my app delegate swift file when I try to run the simulator

Comment: You need `UIWebView.loadRequest(request)`

Comment: you should put `request` into parameter instead of `NSURLRequest`

Comment: Use a instance of NSURLRequest(here is `request`) instead of NSURLRequest

Answer (score 2):

Your `WebView` is subclass of `UIView` rather than `UIWebView`. Fix this issue and then send load request:

```
@IBOutlet var WebView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://heartburncenterofcalifornia.com/testimonials/")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        WebView.loadRequest(request)
    }
```

Comment: I did this and it seemed to be working but when I was in the simulator it paused and now there is a thread 1: signal SIGABRT error oh my